# Quick Question Re Drawables Folders MDPI, HDPI and LDPI

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, scaling

Just a quick question. If I am happy with the way in which Android scales my app on the most common screen sizes (tested on real devices) can I just put my images in the MDPI folder ? Or will this cause problems ?

Thanks !

Comment: *"Just a quick question"*  2 points 1) "What is the meaning of life?"  is a quick question, but it does not mean the answer is quick.  2) You asked two questions - I want a refund of all the micro-seconds it took me to read the second question.  I feel ripped off.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fine but you should really put these in the **drawable** folder to avoid confusion when extending the application further in the future.

Comment: Made a mistake, drawable-nodpi folder is for drawables that you don't want automatically scaled.